# How to connect Acer monitor from Dell laptop?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display, multiple-monitors, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell laptop recent version.
It is connecting to Samsung monitor and other different monitors.
Recently I bought an Acer monitor `KG2410` and it is not detecting on my system.

On Windows 10, it is not showing at all.
On Ubuntu 21.0 live USB, it is showing options in the display settings once I plug in but display not showing in monitor and after 2 min, monitor is going to `standby` mode.

On my brother's MAC, it is connecting and displaying properly.
On my old laptop (7 years old), Windows 7 OS, same monitor is connecting.

It is not working only on my laptop where other monitors work.
And the same Acer monitor works for other systems but not mine.

I kept all drivers upodate from dell support assist and all the windows updates also.
How to fix this?

I even installed Acer Display widget.
And also drivers of Acer `KG241` and `KG241Q`.
Now, in the display widget it is showing the monitor icon but monitor is still showing as "No signal"

Acer menu:

[image]

Comment: Try to install the [KG241 Monitor Driver](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7686?b=1).

Comment: Installed but still not working

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: yeah rebooted multiple times but no use

Comment: If returning this monitor is an option, I would do that.

Comment: Well this monitor working on other systems(mac, my old windows 7 pc). But not in this windows 10

Comment: Sometimes hardware A will not work with B, perhaps because of driver implementation.

Comment: Any work around for this? Like any adapter need to purchase?

Comment: Are you connecting via Vga or Hdmi?

Comment: HDMI, only HDMI port is there for this monitor

Comment: Try another cable.

Comment: Same issue, I bought a new one today

Comment: What is your Dell model and that of the display adapter?